# Proving a Proposition about linear functionals on topological vector spaces.

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I want to show the following:
Let $X$ be a topological vector space (and Hausdorff), $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ a linear functional. Then the following are equivalent:

1.$f$ is continuous

2.$f$ is continuous at $0$

3.$ker(f)$ is closed

From 1 $\Rightarrow$ 2 is obviuos.
So let's start with 2 $\Rightarrow$ 3.
Let $f$ be continuous at $0$.
We have to show that $ker(f)$ is closed.
$ker(f)=\{x \in X: f(x)=0\}=f^{-1}(\{0\})$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed in $\mathbb{K}$ and $f$ is continuous in $0$, $f^{-1}(\{0\})=ker(f)$ is closed.

I do know the following:
Let $X_1,X_2$ be topological spaces, $g:X_1 \rightarrow X_2$. $g$ is continuous iff for every closed subset $S \subseteq X_2$, the set $g^{-1}(S)$ is closed.

Question 1: Since the lin. functional $f$ is assumed to be only continuous at $0$, can I still use the above theorem to conclude that $ker(f)$ is closed?

Question 2:
I do not really know how to conclude 3 $\Rightarrow$ 1.
The only thing that I can think of are the characterizations of continuous maps between topological spaces. I.e. preimage of open sets are open and preimage of closed sets are closed. I assume that I need to combine one of them with the fact that $f$ is a functional, i.e. maps to $\mathbb{K}$. But I can't figure out how to do this part.

Edit:
$2 \Rightarrow 1$:
Since in topological spaces a map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous in $x$ if: for every neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$ there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subseteq V$.

Let $x \in X$ be arbitrary. To verify that $f$ is continuous at $x$, we need to show that there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ s.t. for a neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$: $U$ $\subseteq$ $f(V)$.

So let $V$ be a neighborhood of $f(x)$, then by translation invariance $V-f(x)$ is a neighborhood of $0_{\mathbb{K}}$.
Since $f$ is linear it maps $0_X$ to $0_{\mathbb{K}}$, now by the definition of continuity (in $0_X$) we can find a neighborhood $U$ of $0$ s.t. $f(U) \subseteq V-f(x)$.
Now $U+x$ is a neighborhood of $x$, and using the linearity again $f(x+U)=f(x)+f(U) \subseteq V $, since $f(U)\subseteq V-f(x)$.

So the only thing remaining would be to either show that $3 \Rightarrow 1$ or $3 \Rightarrow 2$.

Comment: I proved the equivalence of (1) and (3) [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4345468/let-e-be-a-t-v-s-and-f-linear-the-hyperplane-x-in-e-mid-fx-alpha?rq=1)...

Comment: For question 1 - no, you cannot use the theorem mentioned. Your argument there proves 1 implies 3, but not 2 implies 3.

Comment: @Akira I did not define bounded on topological vector space yet. So, I do not really understand your solution.

Comment: @Philip $f(U) := \{ f(x) : x \in U \}$ contains real numbers...

Comment: @Akira oh right. Thank you. This makes it easier